# What is meant by CC 7?

Tags: ht, repeater, uv-5r

I am seeing a repeater on [RepeaterBook](https://www.repeaterbook.com/repeaters/Display_SS.php?state_id=41&band=4&loc=%&call=%&use=%)

444.8375
+5 MHz

```
CC 7
```

Portland, Providence Portland Medical Center
Multnomah
WA7HAA
OPEN
ON-AIR

I'd like to programme this on my Baofeng UV5R.

Thanks!

Comment: As an aside - if this is a DMR repeater, you're not going to be able to hear it with a UV5R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the *[Amateur Radio Guide to Digital Mobile Radio](http://www.raqi.ca/~ve2rae/dmr/Amateur_Radio_Guide_to_DMR.pdf)* by W2AXB, CC is the DMR programming "Color Code."